# Cannot create Win32 project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Environment:

- windows 10
- VS 2015 update 3

The scenario is pretty simple:

1. Start VS 2015
2. Open New project wizard and select Win32 project
3. No matter which path is specified after pressing OK the same window appears again.

Does anyone aware how to fix that? Or at least investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by installing "Common Tools for Visual C++"

Answer (score 0):

In my case to solve the problem I had to choose the *"Repair"* option for *Visual Studio Community 2015*. Here is the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx#Anchor_8) to *MSDN* page section describing steps to perform this.

*Note.* Repairing takes some time to be completed. In my case it took more than two hours.